# Авторизация в приложении на CodeIgniter

Tags: framework, php, codeigniter, mysql

Я хочу пересадить свое простое приложение на CodeIgniter. Мне нужна авторизация, причем полная, т.е. куда бы мы не пошли, будучи не авторизованным, нам показывается окошко, куда нужно ввести логин и пароль (вот оно: http://c.meethemes.com/). По документации, как я понял, нужно в контроллере все описывать. Но в каждом контроллере, согласитесь, одно и то же писать не очень удобно.

Как сделать, чтобы нас пускало, когда мы авторизованы?

Вот кстати старая авторизация НЕ на CI:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $login = htmlspecialchars($_POST['login']);
    $pass = md5($md5_prefix.$_POST['pass']);
    if ($login == "" || $pass == "") {
        $error = 'Поля не заполнены';
    }
    else {
        $query = "SELECT login,pass FROM users
                  WHERE login='$login' AND pass='$pass' AND is_active=1";

        if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql($query)) == 0) {
            $error = 'Ошибка авторизации';
        }
        else {
            $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
            header('location: '.$config['url'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А у меня вот такой вот вопрос. В первом случае, до объяснения своими словами вы пишете так: class Mycontroler extends Controller Т.е. расширяете непосредственно ядро. А затем уже в качестве отцовского контроллера выступает Basecontroller, который наследуется от CI_Controllera. class Basecontroller extends CI_Controller Вы это принципиально сделали,или имели в виду, что есть два способа реализации этого дела?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

посмотрите [Система авторизации Ion Auth для Codeigniter](http://code-igniter.ru/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_Ion_Auth)

Comment: Не, это навороченная штука слишком.

Comment: ничего навороченного там нету... все просто и ясно... 

хотите изобретать велосипед... пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте свой контроллер класс (базовый), и в нем проверяйте,

*авторизован* ? или *нет* ? И от этого контроллера наследуйте остальные контроллеры.
Например:

```
class Mycontroler extends Controller {
// тут реализуем проверку
}/*базовый*/
```

а остальные наследуем от базового

```
class Simplecontroller extends Mycontroler 
{}
```

**upd**

Попробую на своих словах объяснить:

В php как и во других яп можно классы наследовать, что означает новый, наследуемый класс тоже будет иметь методы(**public**) родительского класса. Вот по этому мы один раз реализуем проверку авторизаций в родительском классе, и наследуемые классы будеть иметь эту функционал, "с рода", скажем так.

А наследуется со специальным словом **extends**

```
<?php
class Basecontroller extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
             //логика авторизаций, можно средствами своего скрипта, только константу определите главное, и все
               if ($login)
                define('Logged',1);
                else define('Logged',0);
            if (logged) {} else редирект_на_некую_страницу;
         }
}
?>
```

Потом можно спокойно наследовать остальные контроллеры от **Basecontroller-a**

[Php 5 Classes](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.php)

[Наследование в Php](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php)

Comment: Как наследуем? Можно подробнее, пожалуйста? :)